# What should I be aware of when porting javascript mousedown/mouseup/mousemove/keypress listeners to mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile, cross-browser

A script I'm working on samples x/y mouse coordinates to determine a set of user gestures.  It's currently attaching a mousemove event listener to document.body.

New requirements include adding listeners for mousedowns and keypress frequency.  Those are simple enough.  The other new requirement is replicating the interaction listening on mobiles/tablets.

My tentative plan is to avoid device-specific code like the touches object by using the legacy mouse and keypress support.

What challenges should I be aware of?  For example, gotchas where a gesture with a mouse and a gesture with one finger will produce vastly different sets of x/y coordinates on mousemove... or a widely used mobile browser with super-odd event handling.

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html is a wonderful reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you given jQuery Mobile a try? It comes loaded with all the touch gestures you'll ever need. I have used it and can confirm that it works across iOS and Android. Didn't quite test on other platforms though.

There is also this great jQuery plugin called jGestures which gives you access to many events such as touch, tap, pinch and even has a orientation change event.

jGestures: http://jgestures.codeplex.com/

Also I found this interesting page about touch events in Android and iOS and has a list of supported events on each platform: http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html

Forgive me if I've misunderstood your question and posted something unrelated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, your answer appears valid for what the question asked.

Comment: Thanks ninty.  In a way, your answer is "Don't worry about the device-specific challenges, use a x-device library."  

For me, the script must work on its own.  While your answer doesn't exactly answer my question, I would often recommend a library too, so I voted your answer up for anyone else who may read this.